# Extract columns values with spaces in bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, tabular

I have a table output that looks like this:

```
col1     col2            col3     col4
sample1  sample value 1 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 2 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 3 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 4 col3value colvalue4
```

I want to extract the col2 value and print it from the table like this.

```
sample value 1
sample value 2
sample value 3
sample value 4
```

Can someone help me to parse the table and print values with spaces existing between them?

Comment: Your columns must be tab separated to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $2" "$3" "$4}' /your/path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 while IFS=$'\t' read col1 col2 col3 col4; do echo $col2; done < <(cat filepath.ext)
```

This assumes that your output has tabs as separators

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if your table contains tab characters (\t). So I'd like to present you a handy and expandable way to extract what you are looking for. sed, the stream editor is a good command line tool for this.

```
cat the-table.csv | sed -e "s/^[^ ]\+[ ]\+//" -e "s/[ ]\+[^ ]\+$//" -e "s/[ ]\+[^ ]\+$//
```

**Explanation:**

- The first -e parameter cuts of the beginning non space characters and the following space characters
- The second -e parameter cuts off all non space characters at the end including the left hand space characters
- The third -e parameter does the same thing as the second one

**Full Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<FILE | sed -e "s/^[^ ]\+[ ]\+//" -e "s/[ ]\+[^ ]\+$//" -e "s/[ ]\+[^ ]\+$//"
col1     col2            col3     col4
sample1  sample value 1 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 2 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 3 col3value colvalue4
sample1  sample value 4 col3value colvalue4
FILE
```

**Output**

```
col2
sample value 1
sample value 2
sample value 3
sample value 4
```